# Add block drops to player inventory

Tags: java, bukkit

By placing the following code under a `BlockBreakEvent` listener, I'm trying to give the block as an `ItemStack` to the player.

```
Player p = e.getPlayer();
Block b = e.getBlock();
ItemStack im = getDrops(b);
p.getInventory().addItem(im);
p.updateInventory();
```

```
private final ItemStack getDrops(Block b)
{
    for(ItemStack im : b.getDrops())
    {
        return im;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However this gives the block without its data.

Since `b.getDrops()` is a `Collection<ItemStack>`, I then tried this without success:

```
private final ItemStack getDrops(Block b)
{
    ItemStack item = null;
    for(ItemStack im : b.getDrops())
    {
        item = im;
    }
    return item;
}
```

My questions:

- How can I get the block as an `ItemStack` including the block's `MaterialData`?
- Why is this not working fine?

Comment: 1. Read the documentation. 2. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Block.getDrops()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/Block.html#getDrops()) does return [`ItemStack`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html) objects which **do** contain data.

I see many problems with your code:

1. Your first method will return the *first* element only.

   ```
   private final ItemStack getDrops(Block b)
   {
       for(ItemStack im : b.getDrops())
       {
           return im;
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
2. Your second method will return the *last* element only.

   ```
   private final ItemStack getDrops(Block b)
   {
       ItemStack item = null;
       for(ItemStack im : b.getDrops())
       {
           item = im;
       }
       return item;
   }
   ```
3. Also note that some blocks may degenerate when destroyed (like grass to dirt).

I wrote this code.
[`Inventory.addItem(ItemStack...)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html#addItem(org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack...)) implements Java's varargs feature, so that you can pass it an array or a sequence of arguments.

```
PlayerInventory inventory = event.getPlayer().getInventory();
Collection<ItemStack> drops = event.getBlock().getDrops();
inventory.addItem(drops.toArray(new ItemStack[drops.size()]));
```